# Ken Burns zoom in effect using CSS

Tags: css

I was looking at this website-

http://melaniedaveid.com/

And it has a very nice zoom in (Ken Burns effect) on some of the images. I like the smoothness of the animation.

This is the CSS divs use-

```
.project .project__header .header__image {
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
transform: scale(1);
transition: transform 15s linear 0s;
width: 100%;
}
```

I tried doing something similar but this does not work for me. What am I missing?

Comment: There must be more CSS than that...theren't no animation/transition to start with. Use your Developer tools and check more closely.

Comment: There is a `transform: scale(1.3);` on :hover.

Comment: The default scale is 1, I think, so this CSS scales from 1 to 1. The hovered scale should be larger (or smaller). Without the hover value, nothing is going to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the transition happen on hover. So it would look something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/kzam3Lo7/

```
img {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: scale(1);
  width: 100%;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  transition: transform 15s linear 0s;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the transition playing (looping) without a hover?

Comment: That would be an animation. Look into `@keyframes`.